# Объявление и передача массива в аргументе функции

Tags: c++, c, массивы

Хочу создать массив в вызове самой функции. А не сначала создать, затем вызвать функцию.
Пример:

```
void arr_work(int a[] )
{
  a[1] = a[2]+a[2]*a[3];
}

int main ()
{

  arr_work( int {1,2,3} );

}
```

Такое возможно? Как?

Comment: C или C++, выбирайте. :)

Comment: HolyBlackCat, C++